# Execute a Shell Command until Successful

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am installing a list of Jenkins plugins that are listed in a file, using the Jenkins CLI.

However, some installations fail in the first attempt. Once re-tried the installation is successful.
How can I ensure the command that invokes the CLI is tried again?

```
while read line; do
  xargs java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://127.0.0.1:8443/ -noCertificationCheck install-plugin $line
done < plugins.txt
```

Comment: how do you verify if it's installed correctly or not.

Comment: What is in your plugins.txt ? Is it one plugin per line? Correct line endings?

Answer (score 0):

For retries you can use `until` loop, like this:

```
while read line; do
  until java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://127.0.0.1:8443/ -noCertificationCheck install-plugin $line
  do
    echo "retry installing $line"
    sleep 1
  done
done < plugins.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work. It stops after one entry.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but the reason is that your command

> xargs java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://127.0.0.1:8443/
> -noCertifica........

probably reads from standard input and then cause prematuraly exit from the loop.

To avoid this behaviour you have to use a different file descriptor,
by example:

```
while read line <&3; do
  xargs java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://127.0.0.1:8443/ -noCertificationCheck install-plugin $line
done 3< plugins.txt
```